# Unable to set env variable before calling make in shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, makefile

Below is the snippet of my script, which calls the make (GNU), trying to set VERSION env variable before calling `make`

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
MY_VERSION="VERSION=1.0.0"

function build_target() {
   echo ${MY_VERSION} make
   ${MY_VERSION} make
   VERSION=1.0.0 make #this works when I comment out above line.
}
build_target
```

it fails with error

`VERSION=1.0.0 make
./test.sh: line 7: VERSION=1.0.0: command not found`

as mentioned in the code, when I comment out line 7, line 8 works good, why is not taking the value expanded from the variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ...when I comment out line 7, line 8 works good, why is not taking the value expanded from the variable?

Because local environment settings are part of the shell *syntax*, and must be visibly present in the command line, not produced by variable expansion or command substitution. In short, in

```
${MY_VERSION} make
```

there is no environment setting; the syntax for an environment settings is `NAME=WORD`, and there is no `=` in that command.

So the shell expands and word-splits `${MY_VERSION}` and uses the first word in the expansion (`VERSION=1.0.0`) as the name of the command utility to run.

Answer (score 1):

Options would include putting the env setting after the `make` command,

```
$ cat Makefile 
all:
        echo $(VERSION)
$ cat mm
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -e
MY_VERSION="VERSION=1.0.0"

function build_target() {
   make ${MY_VERSION}
}
build_target
$ bash mm
echo 1.0.0
1.0.0
$
```

or, using `env(1)` to then call `make`, e.g. `env ${MY_VERSION} make`

Answer (score 1):

Another option:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
MY_VERSION="1.0.0"

function build_target() {
   echo VERSION=${MY_VERSION} make
   VERSION=${MY_VERSION} make
}
build_target
```